# How to achieve similar UI with UITextField inside UITableView (UITableViewCell)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am looking to mimic the following UI using a UITextField within a UITableViewCell (within a UITableView).  I am new to MonoTouch and I can't seem to figure out what the code would look like for this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple. Just add a *UITextField* with no background color to the cell. Add the below code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
UITextField *inputText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,280,22)];
inputText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
inputText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
inputText.placeHolder = @"Street";
[cell.contentView addSubview:inputText];
[inputText release];
```

Comment: Looking for a MonoTouch solution. Thanks though.

Comment: I was able to derive my solution through your Answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Brian David Berman: Welcome.. But I suggest you to post your answer here(as a new answer), so that it may help others who tries to do exactly what you did.

Answer (score 1):

The cell is a custom cell. It has some properties, a editable UITextField, and a placehold string for empty content. The following code is writed by hand, so maybe there are some bugs inside.

```
@interface EditableCell : UITableViewCell {
   UITextField *mTextField;
}
@property UITextField *textField;

- (void)setPlaceHoldString:(NSString *)placeHolder;
@end

@implement EditableCell
@synthesize textField = mTextField;

- (void)setPlaceHoldString:(NSString *)placeHolder
{
   self.textField.placeHolder = placeHolder;
}

- (UITextField *)textField
{
  if (mTextField == nil) {
      mTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

      // Configure this text field.
      ...

      [self addSubView:mTextField];
  }

   return mTextField;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  self.textField = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but I was looking for the MonoTouch version.  I will try and derive my solution from your Answer though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see that the tag has iPhone.